# Rails store key value for a select input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, helper

I have in my .html.erb:

```
 <label for="form_marital_status">Marital Status:</label>
 <%= select("form", "marital_status", marital_status_options, {}, { }) %>
```

Where `marital_status_options` is defined in my helper as:

```
 def marital_status_options
      %w[Select Single Married Common-Law/Partner Divorced Widowed]
 end
```

Is there a way I can define `marital_status_options` to have a key value pairing for use in the select?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%w[Select Single Married Common-Law/Partner Divorced Widowed]
```

This is going to make the option value and text for each option the same. Return an array of arrays if you want the option value and text to be different for each option. The first value in each array is the text value for the option; the second is the option value itself.

```
def marital_status_options
  [["Select", ""], ["Single", "single"], ["Married", "married"], ["Common-Law/Partner", "partners"], ["Divorced", "divorced"], ["Widowed", "widowed"]] 
end
```

This is explained clearly in [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html).

You should also consider not passing the blank `"Select"` option from your method as there is a way to do this through the `select` method itself.

```
# Helper
def marital_status_options
  [["Single", "single"], ["Married", "married"], ["Common-Law/Partner", "partners"], ["Divorced", "divorced"], ["Widowed", "widowed"]] 
end

# form
<%= select("form", "marital_status", marital_status_options, {:include_blank => "Select"}) %>
```